# How to size a DIV between two fixed attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css

quick question.

I have two navigation bars on a site i'm working on. The first is a fixed-height bar running the width of the screen on the top of the page, the second is a fixed-height bar running the width of the screen on the bottom of the page.

Is there a way to make the content DIV between them resize based on a percentage of the remaining space, rather than the percentage of the total page size? As the window is shrunk vertically, I would like the content div in the middle to resize accordingly while the two bars stay the same size.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two of the most commonly used methods to do this:

**1. Calculate your content's size by subtracting the header + footer height using `calc`**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.bar {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
}

.content {
  background: #aaa;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">Header</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="bar">Footer</div>
```

**2. Use `vh` (viewport height) units to calculate your layout out of `100vh`**

```css
.bar {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 10vh;
}

.content {
  background: #aaa;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">Header</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="bar">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Is that calc() function a new thing? I only do this now and again, i'm still an amateur, but i've never come across that before.

Comment: It's been supported in the major browsers since around 2011 (IE9). Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

1st nav height = 80px, 2nd nav height = 90px; Total 170px;
middle div class = middle-div

```
.middle-div{
    height: calc(100vh - 170px);
}
```

example:

```css
.nav-top, .nav-bottom{
  position: fixed;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #999;
}
.nav-top{
  top: 0;
}
.nav-bottom{
  bottom: 0;
}
.nav-top ul li{
  display: inline;
}
.nav-bottom ul li{
  display: inline;
}
.middle-content{
  background: #555;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-top">
<ul>
<li><button>N M One</button></li>
<li><button>N M Two</button></li>
</ul>
<nav>

<div class="middle-content">

<div>

<nav class="nav-bottom">
<ul>
<li><button>N M One</button></li>
<li><button>N M Two</button></li>
</ul>
<nav>
```